# Google Map Android API OnInfoWindowLongClickListener not available for use

Tags: android, google-maps

The Google Map Android API OnInfoWindowLongClickListener, which is introduced on Dec 17 2015 release, seems not available to be use in Android Studio. Both GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener and GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener are giving me build error 'cannot find symbol'.

I have tried to update Android SDK Platform and Google Play Services, but still not success.

Comment: use the latest play version and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using version 8.4 of Google Play Services, it works fine for me.
Make sure that you're calling it on a GoogleMap reference, and not trying to call it as a static method.

Code:

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap; //instance variable

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowLongClick(Marker marker) {
            //stuff goes here
        }
    });
}
```

Dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```